# Does my Mac App need to apply Server Entitlement Key?

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, xcode, macos

My mac app has a built-in AirPlay function for streaming video file from my app to Apple TV, so do I need a Server Access entitlement key ("com.apple.security.network.server") when submitting it to Mac App Store?

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/EnablingAppSandbox.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011195-CH4-SW9

Comment: If at all, you'd need the _client_ entitlement: _"Both outgoing and incoming connections can send and receive data. The sole difference is in whether your app is initiating the connection or is receiving connections initiated by other apps or other hosts."_ And then: _"Allow Outgoing Connections
com.apple.security.network.client"_

Comment: @DarkDust u mean I need client entitlement instead of server?

Comment: Yes, that's what I wrote.

Comment: @DarkDust since I am initiating the connection to the apple tv so I need client one, am I correct?

Comment: Exactly, your app is acting as a client.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes ! your need that Entitlement Key

If your app connects to the internet, you need to add the following lines to your entitlements.plist:

```
<key>com.apple.security.network.client</key>
<true/>
```

Comment: My mac app has a built-in AirPlay function for streaming video file from my app to Apple TV, so do I need a Server Access entitlement key ("com.apple.security.network.server") when submitting it to Mac App Store?

Comment: your need client entitlement

Comment: since I am initiating the connection to the apple tv so I need client one, am I correct?